# Multiple dropzone in one form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-binding, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone in one single page. In fact, user can add dynamically one object that contains DropZone for instance one City can have N houses and for each house, I let the user send files trough DropZone.

The problem is that I can't bind the uploaded files to the ASP model. At the moment it doesn't even reach the controller.

Here is the HTML it generates:

```
<div class="house0">
<div class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="houseDropzone0">
<div class="dz-default dz-message" data-dz-message="" style="display: block;">
                    <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>

<div class="house1">
<div class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="houseDropzone1">
<div class="dz-default dz-message" data-dz-message="" style="display: block;">
                    <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript I've done:

```
//Foreach houses, create a dropzone element and stock it in the table
var dropzones = [];
var housesList= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.housesList));
for (var i = 0; i < housesList.length; i++) {
                //create the dropzone for the house
                var currentHouse = housesList[i];
                dropzones.push(createHouseDropzoneForId(currentHouse ,i));
            }


//Instanciate each dropzone
function createActionDropzoneForId(id) {
            return new Dropzone("#actionDropzone" + id,
                {
                    url: "/houseUrl/" + id,
                    paramName: 'houseList[' + id+ '].files',
                    autoProcessQueue: false
                });
        }

//Handle the submit event to process the files alongside the data
$("input[type=submit]").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            var form = $(this).closest('form');
            if (form.valid() == true) {
                var dropzones = dropzones;
                dropzones.forEach(function (element) {
                    if (element.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
                        element.processQueue();
                    } else {
                        element.uploadFiles([]); //send empty
                    }
                })

            }

        });
```

Here is the model that should be binded (in my ASP controller):

CITY Class:

```
public class City
    {
        public List<Houses> housesList { get; set; }
        // Other properties as postal code, name, etc
}
```

HOUSE Class:

```
public class House
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase[] files { get; set; }
        // Other properties as color, name, etc
}
```

Comment: @clement Can you post code for your razor view as well?

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is to ensure your razor view contains the @using(Html.BeginForm) directive that will bind the Dropzone elements to the model.

I noticed in your definition of the Dropzone element you are using:

```
...
paramName: 'houseList[' + id+ '].files',
...
```

This should be the cause of the problem as your model currently expects Dropzones with this configuration:

```
...
paramName: 'files',
...
```

To fix this I suggest you augment your model to support multiple dropzones by defining the following properties in the model:

```
public HttpPostedFileBase[] houseList-1-files { get; set; }
public HttpPostedFileBase[] houseList-2-files { get; set; }
public HttpPostedFileBase[] houseList-3-files { get; set; }
```

Also modify the dropzone definition to:

```
...
paramName: 'houseList-' + id+ '-files',
...
```

Then you can modify the received HttpPostedFileBase objects to fit into your usage of:

```
public List<Houses> housesList { get; set; }
```

by instantiating new House objects.